# Simple method to install to Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

There seems to be no simple method to install Ubuntu to Chromebooks, which I know can be done, but it seems like too much hassle. Isn't there an easier way? I don't want to run them side by side, if anything I'd like to replace it or at least have a true dualboot with my Ubuntu being the primary boot.

Comment: Chromebooks aren't really designed to easily install a new OS like other computers, so any method will be a bit more involved. What kind of Chromebook do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP Chromebook 14 and have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it. It's great! I can switch between Chrome OS and Ubuntu. For a laptop that began as a glorified browser, it's now a fully functional "real" operating system! I currently use it for web development. Here are two different links with step by step directions for installing Ubuntu on your Chromebook. Personally, I used Life Hacker's directions, but the other is just as good.

Life Hacker
http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343

Ray Waldo
http://raywaldo.com/2013/01/howto-ubuntu-on-chromebook/